# Java method parameter has state only in debug mode

Tags: java, rest, ejb, mongodb-java

When I call my rest web service and then call a java EJB method (which executes fine), I make an audit of that action in the database. Before I create this record in the database, I get that some parameter sent through method is null.

But when I put a break point on that same spot, that parameter is instantiated and has everything set as it should.

I have another example, where I call some method that creates a document in mongo database collection. And also in debug mode, it creates a document in mongo, but when not in debug mode document is not created.

Comment: How can we help you if there is no code?

Comment: Are your VM arguments the same when running in debug mode?

Comment: The essential thing here: in case your observations are really true, then you must be running in two different environments - something **must** be different. So the question: how do you setup a debug run, and how is that different from what you normally do?

Comment: @nbrooks I am in debug mode in both cases, thing is that only when I put break point the code is being processed.